# where he has been and where he is

Tags: present-perfect

Do the following sentencs both sound okay? If so, what's the difference?

> a. I'm not sure where John has been. He was with you, wasn't he?

> b. I'm not sure where John is. He was with you, wasn't he?

Answer (score 3):

Q. **Do the following sentences both sound okay? If so, what's the difference?**

a. I'm not sure where John has been. He was with you, wasn't he?

b. I'm not sure where John is. He was with you, wasn't he?

---

Both sound OK. the difference is that in the first case John has now returned whilst the second case he is still missing.

**been:** verb
the past participle of be
a) used to say that someone has gone to a place and come back

**is**
the third person singular of the present tense of be

Ref [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/is)

Comment: Thank you. What's your dialect of English?